# Functions with cyclic derivatives

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functions that are their Own nth Derivatives for Real n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/functions-that-are-their-own-nth-derivatives-for-real-n)

Popular function like sine, cos, Sinh, exp, etc. Have the property where for some fixed natural number k and all natural n

$y^{(nk)}=y$

Is the family limited in some sense? Is there a general solution to this whole set of differential equations?

Comment: This was more or less asked here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/functions-that-are-their-own-nth-derivatives-for-real-n/7513#7513

Answer (score 3):

These are all of the form $e^{ax}$ for $a$ being an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of $1$ or linear combinations of them.  For example, $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $i$ is a $4^{\text{th}}$ root of $1$